# how to zip folder every day via Cron Jobs Cpanel

Tags: cron, zip, jobs

How can i make a commend compress folder on zip via Cron Jobs Cpanel 
[elephants](/questions/tagged/elephants)

Answer (score 0):

As root user, edit your crontab:

```
# crontab -e
```

Then add this line:

```
25  6   *   *   *       cd / && run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

That will execute all the scripts located inside the /etc/cron.daily/ directory every day at 6:25. Then you can place a script inside that directory to do desired job. You must grant exec permisions to that script:

```
$ chmod +x script
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hello aicastell, thanks for your answer , but i need a commend like    *   *   *   *       zip /public_html/ ,so can use it from cpanel